# ipad safari scroll freeze in landscape mode on iOS 6

Tags: ios6, safari, scroll

We're experiencing a very strange problem on Safari of iOS6. We have a url which will execute a web program to  show a list of newspaper page images with 2 images per row, it works fine on iPad Safari for over 2 years. However, our users reported recently that when they try to scroll down to bottom so as to see images on last row, Safari just freezes and shows only top half part of the images. Following is our tested results:

1. The problem only exists in iPad/iPhone Safari of iOS6. For iOS5,it's ok.
2. The problem only exists while in landscape mode.
3. The problem only exists when url points to our dynamic web problem.  (We've run this url on Safari of iOS5, then  save the result as a static web page on client side and then upload the static web page (including it's images, js, css files, etc.) to server, then we try to connect this static page on Safari of iOS6    under landscape mode, but the result is ok? the static page's url is `http://210.243.166.84:98/test/ttt/ttt.html` (note: Sorry!, Stackoverflow doesn't allow numeric ip, so please copy the url to your own browser)

Does anyone know or ever have solve same/similar problem as we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the cause and astonishingly, this problem actually exists in Safari on all version of iOS. Our servlet is called within a frame of our index.html, as following codes:

```
<frameset rows="0,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="/untitled.htm" name="top">
  <frame src="/myapp/myIndex">
</frameset><noframes></noframes>
    <frame>
```

In page generated by myIndex, there's an anchor:

```
<a href='myapp/iPadNews'>
```

If we connect to index.html, page generated by ipadNews is actually a descendant of the frame. We guess, for unkown reason, Safari calculates wrong for scrolling and think the bottom of page is already reached before it is actually shown on screen. The reason why it's only happened in landscape mode is maybe the image is larger when in landscape mode and the problem happens earlier than that in portait mode. If we add more images in the page, maybe the problem will happen even in portait mode.

The alternative we take is adding a 'target=_blank' in ahchor and the problem goes away, as following code:

```
<a href='myapp/iPadNews' target=_blank>
```